# Can I assign a value to a variable inside of an update statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm kinda new to Oracle and I was wondering, if I can assign a value to a variable inside of an `update statement case`.

I have this code so far:

```
PROCEDURE insert_repayment_data_inst(

  date_of_payment_l             IN credit_mo_repayment.date_of_payment%TYPE,
  amoount_to_pay_l              IN credit_mo_repayment.ammount_to_pay%TYPE,
  client_number_l               IN credit_mo_repayment.client_number%TYPE,
  is_paid_l                     IN credit_mo_repayment.is_paid%TYPE, 
  month_l                       IN credit_mo_repayment.is_paid%TYPE,
  year_l                        IN credit_mo_repayment.is_paid%TYPE,
  ending_balance_l              IN credit_mo_repayment.ending_balance%TYPE,
  tests                         IN credit_mo_repayment.ending_balance%TYPE
) AS
  BEGIN

  select monthly_installment into tests
  from credit_mo_repayment
   WHERE (to_char(date_of_payment, 'mm') = to_char(to_date(date_of_payment_l), 'mm'))
         AND (to_char(date_of_payment, 'yy') = to_char(to_date(date_of_payment_l), 'yy'));

  UPDATE credit_mo_repayment
  SET

  monthly_installment = CASE 
                          WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l >= 0)  THEN Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l
                          WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l < 0) THEN 0
                        END,

  ending_balance = CASE
                     WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l < 0) THEN ending_balance - ABS(Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l) tests:= ending_balance - ABS(Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l)
                     WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l >= 0)  THEN ending_balance
                   END,
  ammount_to_pay = ammount_to_pay + amoount_to_pay_l
  WHERE (to_char(date_of_payment, 'mm') = to_char(to_date(date_of_payment_l), 'mm'))
         AND (to_char(date_of_payment, 'yy') = to_char(to_date(date_of_payment_l), 'yy'));                                  
END insert_repayment_data_inst;
```

As you can see I'm trying to assign the value to the variable inside of the case like this
`tests:= ending_balance - ABS(Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l)`

But without luck.

I have also tried to assign the `monthly_installment` value to the `tests` variable and then just to do the math, but I also had no luck.

```
 select monthly_installment into tests
 from credit_mo_repayment
 WHERE (to_char(date_of_payment, 'mm') = to_char(to_date(date_of_payment_l), 'mm'))
        AND (to_char(date_of_payment, 'yy') = to_char(to_date(date_of_payment_l), 'yy'));
```

I know that I'm missing something in the syntax, but I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to select into tests? Errormessage?

Comment: @Armunin `Error(683,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`, `Error(683,35): PLS-00403: expression 'TESTS' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement`, `Error(684,3): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier`

Comment: Are you sure that `tests` is of the correct type? Is `ending_balance` the same type as `monthly_installment`?

Comment: @Armunin yes both are the same. I just changed it and got exactly the same errors :(

Comment: Ah... `tests` is defined as `IN` parameter of your function not as variable... change that or define a new variable

Comment: Don't do these may calculations while updating the table..you can declare monthly installment and ending balance as variables..do all calculation and finally update the table..it will make things easier for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to define your target variable as an `OUT`-Parameter or a new variable. For example:

```
PROCEDURE insert_repayment_data_inst(

  date_of_payment_l             IN credit_mo_repayment.date_of_payment%TYPE,
  amoount_to_pay_l              IN credit_mo_repayment.ammount_to_pay%TYPE,
  client_number_l               IN credit_mo_repayment.client_number%TYPE,
  is_paid_l                     IN credit_mo_repayment.is_paid%TYPE, 
  month_l                       IN credit_mo_repayment.is_paid%TYPE,
  year_l                        IN credit_mo_repayment.is_paid%TYPE,
  ending_balance_l              IN credit_mo_repayment.ending_balance%TYPE,
  tests                         IN credit_mo_repayment.ending_balance%TYPE
) AS
-- new variable
  monthly_payments_output credit_mo_repayment.ending_balance%TYPE;
  BEGIN
```

Second: you can try the `RETURNING`-clause as described here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#BABHDGIG and here
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABEBDIA
Which should result in something like this (untested):

```
UPDATE credit_mo_repayment
  SET

  monthly_installment = CASE 
                          WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l >= 0)  THEN Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l
                          WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l < 0) THEN 0
                        END,

  ending_balance = CASE
                     WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l < 0) THEN ending_balance - ABS(Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l)
                     WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l >= 0)  THEN ending_balance
                   END,
  ammount_to_pay = ammount_to_pay + amoount_to_pay_l
  WHERE (to_char(date_of_payment, 'mm') = to_char(to_date(date_of_payment_l), 'mm'))
         AND (to_char(date_of_payment, 'yy') = to_char(to_date(date_of_payment_l), 'yy'))
RETURNING monthly_installment INTO tests;
```

Comment: Here is what I got: `Error(711,20): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "MONTHLY_INSTALLMENT" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; `

Comment: It's hard to test or reproduce for me without any testdata. There may be some syntax errors in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
UPDATE credit_mo_repayment SET
monthly_installment = 
    CASE 
    WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l >= 0) THEN Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l
    WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l < 0) THEN 0
    END,
ending_balance = 
    CASE
    WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l < 0) THEN ending_balance - ABS(Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l) 
    WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l >= 0) THEN ending_balance
    END,
ammount_to_pay = ammount_to_pay + amoount_to_pay_l
WHERE (TO_CHAR(date_of_payment, 'mm') = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_of_payment_l), 'mm'))
    AND (TO_CHAR(date_of_payment, 'yy') = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_of_payment_l), 'yy'))
RETURNING  
    CASE
   WHEN (Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l < 0) THEN ending_balance - ABS(Monthly_installment - amoount_to_pay_l)
    ELSE NULL
    END         
INTO tests;
```

Not tested - I am not sure if CASE expression is allowed in RETURNING clause.